# Basic Authentication in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, basic-authentication

I am trying to setup Basic Authentication for my CakePHP app so I can use it as an API for an upcoming mobile application. However If I pass the following:

`cameron:password@dev.driz.co.uk/basic/locked/`

Where cameron is the username, password is the password, and the rest is the domain and application. `locked` is a method that requires authentication. *(obviously the password is wrong in this example)*

**(Q1)** I will be requested for a username and password in a prompt... but the username and password are in fact correct as if I then type them into the prompt they work... **Why would this happen?** Haven't I just passed the username and password?

I can't see anything wrong with the way I have set this up in CakePHP.

I set Basic Auth in AppController as:

```
public $components = array('Auth');

function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();

    $this->Auth->authorize = array('Controller');
    $this->Auth->authenticate = array('Basic');
    $this->Auth->sessionKey = false;
    $this->Auth->unauthorizedRedirect = false;

}
```

**(Q2)** Even so I have set both sessions to be false and the redirect to false, if the user cancels the prompt then they are redirected to the login page? Any ideas on how to stop this from happening? Ideally I want to send back a JSON response or status code of 401 (depending if it's an AJAX request or not).

So something like:

```
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

    $response = json_encode(
            array(
                'meta'=>array(
                    'code'=>$this->response->statusCode(401),
                    'in'=>round(microtime(true) - TIME_START, 4)
                ),
                'response'=>array(
                    'status'=>'error',
                    'message'=>'401 Not Authorized'
                )
            )
        );

    // Handle JSONP
    if(isset($_GET['callback'])) {
        $response = $_GET['callback'] . '(' . $response . ')';
    }

    // Return JSON
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $this->response->type('json');
    $this->response->body($response);   

} else {

    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');

}
```

But where would this go in the application logic to show this? It needs to happen for ALL requested methods that require authentication and user fails or cancels the authentication.

**(Q3)** If you enter incorrect details you are just shown the prompt again until you get the username/password correct or hit cancel. How can I make it show an error?

Any ideas for these three issues (marked as sub questions numbers).

Update: This is how I send the headers to the API:

```
"use strict";jQuery.base64=(function($){var _PADCHAR="=",_ALPHA="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/",_VERSION="1.0";function _getbyte64(s,i){var idx=_ALPHA.indexOf(s.charAt(i));if(idx===-1){throw"Cannot decode base64"}return idx}function _decode(s){var pads=0,i,b10,imax=s.length,x=[];s=String(s);if(imax===0){return s}if(imax%4!==0){throw"Cannot decode base64"}if(s.charAt(imax-1)===_PADCHAR){pads=1;if(s.charAt(imax-2)===_PADCHAR){pads=2}imax-=4}for(i=0;i<imax;i+=4){b10=(_getbyte64(s,i)<<18)|(_getbyte64(s,i+1)<<12)|(_getbyte64(s,i+2)<<6)|_getbyte64(s,i+3);x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10>>16,(b10>>8)&255,b10&255))}switch(pads){case 1:b10=(_getbyte64(s,i)<<18)|(_getbyte64(s,i+1)<<12)|(_getbyte64(s,i+2)<<6);x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10>>16,(b10>>8)&255));break;case 2:b10=(_getbyte64(s,i)<<18)|(_getbyte64(s,i+1)<<12);x.push(String.fromCharCode(b10>>16));break}return x.join("")}function _getbyte(s,i){var x=s.charCodeAt(i);if(x>255){throw"INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: DOM Exception 5"}return x}function _encode(s){if(arguments.length!==1){throw"SyntaxError: exactly one argument required"}s=String(s);var i,b10,x=[],imax=s.length-s.length%3;if(s.length===0){return s}for(i=0;i<imax;i+=3){b10=(_getbyte(s,i)<<16)|(_getbyte(s,i+1)<<8)|_getbyte(s,i+2);x.push(_ALPHA.charAt(b10>>18));x.push(_ALPHA.charAt((b10>>12)&63));x.push(_ALPHA.charAt((b10>>6)&63));x.push(_ALPHA.charAt(b10&63))}switch(s.length-imax){case 1:b10=_getbyte(s,i)<<16;x.push(_ALPHA.charAt(b10>>18)+_ALPHA.charAt((b10>>12)&63)+_PADCHAR+_PADCHAR);break;case 2:b10=(_getbyte(s,i)<<16)|(_getbyte(s,i+1)<<8);x.push(_ALPHA.charAt(b10>>18)+_ALPHA.charAt((b10>>12)&63)+_ALPHA.charAt((b10>>6)&63)+_PADCHAR);break}return x.join("")}return{decode:_decode,encode:_encode,VERSION:_VERSION}}(jQuery));

            $(document).ready(function(){

                var username = 'cameron';

                var password = 'password';

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://dev.driz.co.uk/basic/locked',
                    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
                        var base64 = $.base64.encode(username + ':' + password);
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
                    },
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(data) {

                        console.log(data);

                    },
                    error: function(a,b,c) {
                        //console.log(a,b,c);
                    }
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 2):

### Q1

You don't specify how you visit the protected URL (dev.driz.co.uk/basic/locked). Are you sure that the way you are doing it you are setting up the request headers properly? You need to Base64 encode the username/password.

When your first request fails the browser jumps in with the prompt and to be succeeding means that the browser does it properly for you the second time.

Have a look at you request headers to see what you send the first time and what the browser sends the second.

### Q2

When basic auth fails your server sends a `401` with a header `WWW-Authenticate:Basic` which is picked up from the browser and you are presented with the prompt. That is build in normal behavior for all browsers since ages, you can't change that.

About your issue with canceling and being redirected to login, Auth had some API changes after 2.4 that are highlighted in the book. Before version 2.4 you are always redirected to loginAction.

Finally, let `Auth` do the work for you by setting it up properly and don't attempt to hardwire the responses yourself like in the code you suggest. You also shouldn't *ever* be using php's `header()` in cakephp, use `CakeRequest::header()` instead.

### Q3

Answered in Q2, you can't have Basic and 401 not trigger the prompt. Either change the required authentication header (by perhaps setting a name like Basic-x instead of Basic) or don't send the response code 401 on failure but send i.e. 200 or 400 and add an error message explaining the situation.

Comment: For Q3 when you say `or don't send the response code 401 on failure but send i.e. 200 or 400 and add an error message explaining the situation.` how do you do this? It sounds like you imply you can do this without changing the header... Could you show an example?

Comment: You can create your own custom exception and give the status code as the second parameter or raise a [buildin exception](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp)

Comment: I've updated my CakePHP code to 2.5.2 but when I do the above posted JS code I see the login prompt from the browser... so it's as though it's requesting authentication to be able to actually send the request via AJAX if that makes sense? Even though the headers are being set in the beforeSend option! Can you see any reason why? The username and password are correct, as if I type them into the prompt it then works! But even if they were incorrect, I don't want to see the prompt and instead show an error in my JS only...

Comment: I don't know if your base64 function is correct, I would use the internal function ``btoa()`` to encode it which works. And if you don't want the prompt read what I explain in Q3, where I'm talking about the headers being sent from the server.

Comment: Tried that, but the headers are never sent (looking in the web inspector) because it doesn't have access to send them as it's not authorized yet... and if I enter my details into the prompt then refresh the page with that JS on, then the headers are sent by the JS... why is that happening? I thought beforeSend handled this so it send the headers BEFORE the request?

Comment: Again - you're confusing the headers that are sent as part of the request (from the client to the server) and the headers that are sent as part of the response (from the server to the client). Auth fails because your request headers are (most probably) wrong. The prompt gets triggered because the response headers contain 401 and Basic.

Comment: I'm not confused, I know the difference. The headers should be correct. As when I authenticate via the prompt the **request** headers are sent fine and work... If they were incorrect they wouldn't work here either but they do. It's literally like they can't be sent the first time as the unauthorized state prevents anything from being sent through!

Comment: Then your reply ``the headers are never sent because it doesn't have access to send them as it's not authorized yet`` doesn't make sense. Basic authentication should be stateless, meaning you should be sending username+password in each request, including the first. If you are waiting for the browser to reply with 401 or if you auth through the browser and then you're allowed in for all subsequent requests you're doing it wrong. If your js request fails and the browser's succeeds then this has nothing to do with cakephp and the subject or parts of the question.

Comment: I am sending the username and password in each AJAX request (you can see that in my code above). But for some reason the headers are not being sent.. they ONLY get sent when I have previously authorized.

Comment: Alright then, but that's a different problem (JS/Jquery related) and irrelevant to the issues at hand which I believe are answered fully. This thread can't mutate to go on forever, please open a new question with relevant information (how you call your JS, from what file at what url, what are the request headers, etc) if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Okay I've found out that using JSONP with jQuery means that the headers don't get sent! BUT if you say that Basic Auth is stateless... how come the browser is remembering the username and password (once authenticated) and keeping the user authenticated and meaning that I can then make requests WITHOUT having to the send the headers for subsequent requests. So I can only presume there is some issue on the CakePHP end that is allowing this to happen.

Comment: I've asked a new question about this very problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678810/basic-authentication-not-stateless