# Basic Authentication not stateless

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm trying to use Basic Authentication in a CakePHP API that I can talk to using jQuery.

Running this code works fine:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://username:password@domain.com',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
        }
});
```

*Note: I put the username and password in the URL because otherwise the headers wouldn't be sent using JSONP as the datatype and then using beforeSend, etc.*

However, then running this code as a REPLACEMENT for the above AFTER running the above also works **(notice I'm not sending the username and password anymore)**.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://domain.com',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
        }
});
```

The browser is remembering the user, so the code no longer needs the headers to make requests to the CakePHP API. But if it's stateless... this shouldn't be happening right?

**I thought you HAD TO send the headers with each request to Basic Authentication?**

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 1):

During the first request the server actually issues a WWW-Authenticate field in the response headers and responds to you a challenge authentication asking you to enter a correct username and password. In your case you included them to the URL.

The next time you send a request again to the server, the client's request header will now have an Authorization field included in it (i.e. `Authorization: Basic c2RmZ2RmZzpkYWRmZHNmcw==`). `c2RmZ2RmZzpkYWRmZHNmcw==` is basically a base 64 encoded string that the client includes to the headers for every succeeding requests so that the server will not respond with a challenge authentication each time. By doing a base 64 decode to the string you will see that the value is basically a combination of username and password (i.e. `dfgdfg:dadfdsfs`) in the format `<username>:<password>`.

Now if you try to close the browser the Authorization field will be destroyed and the server will ask again for the correct username and password once you try to issue a request again. You can actually bypass including the username and password in the URL in plain text. Just include an `Authorization` field in your request header. Just be sure that the : value is base 64-encoded correctly and include the type `Basic` to it.

Comment: But if I refresh the page the previous requests should be forgotten right? Otherwise this isn't stateless. And Basic Authentication is supposed to be stateless.

Comment: HTTP is stateless that is why the client needs to send again and again the Authorization HTTP header field.

Comment: But why is it sending it if it's not in the JS code? I.e remembering the authorized user.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* make it stateless to make sense in the form of an API but this is not *mandatory* by the standard as Basic Auth could be used with normal requests to gain access to protected resources via the browser.

Like in normal authentication your code could be setting a session that remembers the user for subsequent requests. Look for a cookie response or add the complete code.

Also remember that Basic auth and http (without SSL) are a match for disaster as the credentials will be sent as part of the request unencrypted.

Comment: How do you make CakePHP's Basic Authentication stateless? As I was under the impression that it wasn't the case of sessions (which I have disabled) but something else.

Comment: @Cameron late response, but if you use sessions then it's not stateless.  For it to be stateless you have to pass all details everytime to the server. So by turning off cookies/sessions you should naturally have a stateless system. The server should have no idea who you are and where you've been before on the server with each new request.